# How to generate .lib files with mingw toolchain?

Tags: gcc, g++, mingw, llvm

I have installed MingW GCC 4.8.1 in my system. I am trying to build the LLVM source code( with some extra modification). Cmake 2.8.12 is used to generate the makefiles and visual studio solution files. I am able to build the LLVM source (Rel 3.4.2) with Visual Studio 2010 And is generating both lib and dll file. But with MingW I am not able generate .lib files by simply running `Make all`.

How to make MingW generate .lib file while building the project ?

Comment: When using MinGW most people follow the Unix convention use the `.a` extension with libraries, and often prefix the name with `lib`. For example, `libfoo.a` instead of `foo.lib`. See if `.a` files are being generated instead.

Comment: @RossRidge Thanks yea .a files are there. and It worked thanks :)

Comment: @RossRidge I think the corresponding file for dll is the `libfoo.dll.a` file, it seems that `libfoo.a` is the full archive file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CMAKE_GNUtoMS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_GNUtoMS.html). Add `-DCMAKE_GNUtoMS=ON` to the build command. See [this CMake issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19171). As result, a `.lib` file will be generated along with the `.dll.a` file.